# As a Hungarian national, can I enter the Schengen area through Austria, while traveling from Tanzania?

Tags: driving, covid-19, austria, tanzania, hungarian-citizens

I plan on traveling to Zanzibar, Tanzania. I would drive from Budapest to Vienna, then fly from there though either Doha or Dubai. As far as I know, this part of my itinerary would be difficulty-free, at least when it comes to coronavirus-related border closures and travel restrictions.

However, I'm not sure whether the same can be said about the return journey. I have been browsing [this site](https://www.austria.info/en/service-and-facts/coronavirus-information/entry-regulations) for general information about the restrictions. I haven't found the answer.

**The question**: is it possible for me to travel to Austria from Tanzania? The site doesn't list my African destination in either the "open borders" or the "high-risk countries", so I'm not sure whether it's possible *at all*.

Thanks.

Comment: It might be better to ask this as two separate questions.

Comment: @phoog In retrospect, I agree! I haven't really paid any attention to the fact that the two questions were indeed *different*, and that they were interconnected only in my, granted: rather special, case. The second questions has therefore been removed, and will be reposted when applicable, ie. if my journey is found to be viable and legal, after all. [at]Everyone else: I don't think downvotes are fair. I believe my question showed research effort, and it was neither unclear nor not useful. Feel free to comment, though. I am interested in your constructive opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find an official English translation, but [this web page from the Austrian government on Covid related travel restrictions](https://www.oesterreich.gv.at/themen/freizeit_und_strassenverkehr/reisen_und_ferien/Reisebeschr%C3%A4nkungen-durch-das-Coronavirus.html) answers your question:

(my translation)

> When a person in one of the previously mentioned groups (Austrian, EU,
> EEA and Swiss citizens) enters Austria from all other states (which
> are not in the groups of states with a stable or instable Covid-19
> situation), the person must either:
>
> - present a negative PCR test, which is not older than 72 hours
> - or quarantine for 10 days
>
> The qurantine can be lifted following a negative PCR test.

The difference is that if you enter from a country with an instable Covid-19 situation, you *must* take a PCR test in Austria within 48 hours if you don't present a recent negative test at the border. If you come from other countries, the PCR test in Austria is voluntary.

I don't find any particular requirements for the foreign PCR tests or if the test result must be presented in a specific language.

Be aware that this is the *current* set of rules. Everything may have changed when you return from Tanzania at some point in the future.